# How to configure pom.xml for generate jooq classes into two different packages?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, code-generation, jooq

My project consists of two packages, each of which uses the same database schema. In the future, both packages will become independent microservices.

**Question:** how to configure code generation in **pom.xml** so that folders with jooq classes are created in two different packages (`myProject/packageTwo/ Dao` and `myProject/packageOne/Dao`).

For example, this decision results in jooq classes being created only in the second folder.

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
  <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
  <version>3.15.3</version>
…
   <target>
        <packageName>myProject/packageOne/Dao</packageName>
        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
  </target>
  <target>
        <packageName> myProject/packageTwo/Dao</packageName>
        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
  </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Maven question than a jOOQ one: You should configure two separate executions in order to have two separate target configurations:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
  <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>

  <!-- shared configuration, can also be moved to pluginManagement -->
  <configuration>...</configuration>

  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>exec-1</id>
      <phase>...</phase>
      <goals><goal>generate</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <generator>
          <target>...</target>
        </generator>
      </configuration>
    </execution>

    <execution>
      <id>exec-2</id>
      <phase>...</phase>
      <goals><goal>generate</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <generator>
          <target>...</target>
        </generator>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```